# Printing via Adobe Reader under Linux and CUPS

Tags: linux, printing, adobe-reader

I have a Gestetner printer, installed via CUPS and working under other pdf readers like Evince.

However, with Adobe Reader, I get an error:

```
lpq : Gestetner : unknown printer
```

`lpstat -a` lists the printer as accepting requests, however `lpr -P Gestetner_MP7500` yields again the `unknown printer` error.

One workaround I have found is installing cupsys-bsd, which removes lpr. The only annoyance(!) is that it crashes now when I select duplex and click OK.

I am running Debian by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I know that maybe you'd already tried this solution, but I remember myself searching for a similar solution the last year, and it tooks me a couple of weeks to figure it out...(yes, I'm that kind of n00b, guys! :D).

So, have you tried to browse [your CUPS webservice](http://localhost:631/)?

Hope that helps.

Regards

Comment: Good suggestion. Most of my CUPS problems have been fixed by this method.

Comment: Yes, actually the web service is the only tool I use with CUPS. The problem is with the Adobe Reader I guess, however as far as I understand, cupsys-bsd provides its own lpr binary instead of the package lpr; so that should be preferred. Why Debian by default installs lpr is beyond me, however.

Comment: See `apt-file search lpr | egrep '/lpr$'`

Both provide lpr binaries I guess. Actually, the new package name seems to be called `cups-bsd`, not `cupsys-bsd` which has become an obsolete transitional package.